# When clicked counter goes up when unclicked counter goes down again

Tags: jquery, html

I got the task to make a table that was clickable and when you clicked on a certain row it turns green. i figured that out but now i have to make it that when a row goes green the counter goes up, and when its unclicked it needs to go down again.
someone please help :P

```
 <style>
.green-cell {
   background: rgb(29, 247, 0); 
}
</style>


<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table: <button id="clickme"> 0</button> </p>            
  <table class="table " id="onclick" >
    <thead>
      <tr >
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <td >John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
      $( function() {
    $('tr').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");



    count += 1;
    button.innerHTML =   count;



    } );
    } );

    var button = document.getElementById("clickme"),
     count = 0;
    button.onclick = function() {
    count += 1;
    button.innerHTML =   count;
};


    </script>
```

Comment: after you toggle the class, detect whether the row [currently has the class or not](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), and then alter the count accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $( function() {
    $('tr').click( function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count += 1;
    } else {
      count -= 1;
    }
    button.innerHTML =   count;
    } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

After you toggle the class, you detect whether the row currently has the class or not, and then alter the count accordingly. For this you can use jQuery's [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var countEl = $("#count");
  var count = 0;

  $('tbody tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("green-cell");
    if ($(this).hasClass("green-cell")) {
      count++;
    } else {
      count--;
    }
    countEl.html(count);
  });
});
```

```css
.green-cell {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}

td, th {
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:hover {
  background: rgb(29, 247, 0);
}

tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  Count: <span id="count"> 0</span>
  <br/><br/>
  <table class="table " id="onclick">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i understand it now. Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: @SjoerdvandenHoogen no problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the question so that it turns green) - thankyou

Comment: @SjoerdvandenHoogen P.S. You might notice in the code above I corrected / improved one or two other things as well: include missing `<tr>` opening tags; use jQuery consistently throughout to select elements; use `++` and `--` shorthand operators to increase/decrease by 1; add some better CSS style to the table; use a `<span>` instead of a button as a more appropriate element for displaying output (buttons are for accepting input, after all).

Comment: yes i noticed the improvements quite a lot , im still learning at school so im quite the noob if i say so my self. really appreciate the help :)

Comment: i have another problem if you could help, i need the total amount of green rows but it also needs to count the "<th> Count <th> ", for example if youd click on july the total should be 4. could you please help me with that aswell? :3

Comment: @SjoerdvandenHoogen if you have a new problem please ask a new question about it, thanks. That's the way this site works. The comments are not for extended discussion or adding code samples. P.S. If you add a link to your new question in these comments I will be happy to take a look :-)

Comment: im not allowed to post another question for the coming 2 days sadly :/